Duplicate key name while creating indexes in Python for MySQL
A am currently doing a time analysis on SQL queries using MySQL, where each query uses one type of operation and for each query I test with B Tree and Hash indices. The following code is responsible for creating the indices and calling a function that do the query a number of times.
def instanceProcessing(queryInstance):

    # queryInstance[0] is a queryId
    print(queryInstance[0] + "\n")

    # Add the analyze keyword
    # queryInstance[1] is the SQL
    querySQL = "EXPLAIN ANALYZE " + queryInstance[1]

    # Test without indices
    print("  No index")
    executionLoop(queryInstance[0], querySQL, "ni", "")

    # Tests with B Tree
    # queryInstance[2] is a list with the indices (relation.atribute)
    for testIndices in queryInstance[2]:

        print("  B+ tree - " + testIndices)
        relationName, attributeName = testIndices.split(".")
        indexOn = relationName + " (" + attributeName + ")"
        indexName = queryInstance[0] + "Btree" + relationName + atributeName

        # Create the index
        try:
            createIndexQuery = "CREATE INDEX " + indexName + " USING BTREE ON " + indexOn
            myCursor = mydb.cursor()
            myCursor.execute(createIndexQuery)
            myCursor.fetchall()

        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print("  *** Something went wrong creating B+ tree: {}".format(err) + "\n")
            continue

        # Do the query
        executionQuery(queryInstance[0], querySQL, "btree", testIndices)

        # Delete index
        deleteIndexQuery = "DROP INDEX " + indexName + " ON " + tableName
        myCursor = mydb.cursor()
        myCursor.execute(deleteIndexQuery)
        myCursor.fetchall()

    # Tests with Hash
    for testIndices in queryInstance[2]:

        print("  Hash - " + testIndices)
        relationName, attributeName = testIndices.split(".")
        indexOn = relationName + " (" + attributeName + ")"
        indexName = queryInstance[0] + "Hash" + relationName + atributeName

        # Create index
        try:
            createIndexQuery = "CREATE INDEX " + indexName + " USING HASH ON " + indexOn
            myCursor = mydb.cursor()
            myCursor.execute(createIndexQuery)
            myCursor.fetchall()

        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            print("  *** Something went wrong creating Hash index: {}".format(err) + "\n")
            continue

        # Do the query
        queryLoop(queryInstance[0], querySQL, "hash", testIndices)

        # Delete index
        deleteIndexQuery = "DROP INDEX " + indexName + " ON " + tableName
        myCursor = mydb.cursor()
        myCursor.execute(deleteIndexQuery)
        myCursor.fetchall()

The problem I am having has to do with the creation of the indices. I tried to name them in a unique way, so I would not create to indices with the same name, even if I delete them right after using. The names are:
# B Tree
indexName = queryInstance[0] + "Btree" + relationName + attributeName

# Hash index
indexName = queryInstance[0] + "Hash" + relationName + attributeName

But sometimes when running, i get the error Something went wrong creating B+ tree: 1061 (42000): Duplicate key name '7bBtreePostsPostTypeId', but I don't see how this is possible. In this example, there is only one query with id 7b, and the index on Posts(PostTypeId) with B Tree is tested only once. Is there something I am missing?
Sometimes this happens when I am creating index on a Key, sometimes on a foreign keys. It also happens to indexes over relations and attributes that worked before.  I don't see a pattern. Thanks in advance!
I even tried creating names using uuid to be unique and avoid repetition, but I still got the error. I was expecting that different index names would not be a problem.

Please post add the value of queryInstance to the question.

Are you sure the table does not already have an index with the name you are trying to add? use SHOW CREATE TABLE when you get the error to double-check.

Which storage engine are you using? Are you aware that neither InnoDB nor MyISAM support hash indexes? See table 15.1 in this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html
